# Library for styling like airbnb ios app in JQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a navbar in jquery mobile which seems to airbnb ios app style:

In the left side, the grey bar with a kind of arrow:

http://photos2.appleinsider.com/gallery/9900-1860-140716-Airbnb-l.png

Like this:

http://a2.mzstatic.com/au/r30/Purple3/v4/fc/43/1c/fc431c1e-056a-4031-f5a0-e269126f5721/screen322x572.jpeg

Or this right photo:

http://www.imore.com/sites/imore.com/files/styles/xlarge/public/field/image/2014/04/airbnb_iphone_best_apps_screens.jpg?itok=9Zji5vsP

I want to include that arror in my navbars. Is it possible? I haven't found anything on the internet but maybe there is a library or something I haven't found.

If not, any idea to try to get this or something similar?

Comment: I don't know why I got a close and -2 points. I just asked about a css question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this triangle shape using borders in css. Check this example:

```css
nav {
  overflow: hidden;
background-color: #ddd;  
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  }

nav li {
  float: left
  
  }
nav a {
    display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
  }
nav a:hover:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #fff;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<nav>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Something like that but when I quit the mouse (or finger, it is for a mobile web page) the triangle keeps there until I change the button.

Comment: This is just a basic example of how you could style the control. Thats how touch screen devices emulate 'hover' state of a mouse. If you want to improve the UX then you would probably need to add some javascript. I'm not sure the functionality you are aiming for exactly

Comment: I want to change the div each time someone click on one element. I already have that done. Using what you did, I just need to keep the triangle when some press an element, not just when hover over it. I will try yo use your code, thanks.

Comment: You will need to add an 'active' class (using js) when you click the item. then style the triangle with the .active class rather than the :hover state.

Comment: yes, and also I did with focus to keep active when you move the mouse.